# Как запретить редактировать свойство тэга (disabled) на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html

При нажатии на кнопку отправляется ajax запрос на сервер и на кнопку ставится disabled,но если через код элемента удалить disabled, то запрос снова отправляется при нажатии. Что делать ?

Comment: ничего, тот кто может убрать атрибут disabled может и просто сразу запрос послать, а тот кому это не надо - и не столкнется с проблемой

Comment: Очевидно, нужно проверять на сервере, допустимо ли выполнять запрошенное действие

Comment: Можно в коде поставить флаг, который после первого запроса запретит делать второй

Comment: установить секундную периодичность установки disabled, тогда будет чуть труднее её убирать.

Comment: @Опан, тогда отключается js и спокойно убирается все :) и в нет смысла в этом случае вообще что-то делать с разметкой, если можно сразу слать запрос нужный с какими угодно данными